# MS word remove XML like tags

Tags: ms-word, find, wildcard

This is a an MS word question. I have a document with some xml like tags and I want to remove some specific tags.

Here's a sample text

```
<tagname/>
<anothertag/>
<sectiontag>some text</sectiontag>
<tagname/>
```

so in this case I want to replace anything in the form `<sometext/>` with nothing. I've used a few variations of `\<*/\>` and that works fine exept that it matches

```
<sectiontag>some text</sectiontag>
<tagname/>
```

when in that case, I only want `<tagname/>` matched, the other text does not qualify as a single tag.
Not sure if any of that makes sense. It's for a bespoke document processing application if you need to know.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for *programming* issues. Your question really belongs in an end-user venue such as Super User or Microsoft Answers.

Comment: This is kind of programming related as I'm writing a document processing application in VBA to replace XML like tags with text from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have the answer, it's

```
\<([!\<\>]@/\>)
```

And to search and highlight start and end tags in the form `<tagname>stuff</tagname>`

use

```
\<([!\<\>]@\>)*\</\1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete both tags with a single *wildcard* Find/Replace expression, where:

Find = \<([!\<]@\>)(*)\</\1

Replace = \2